# Xcode 9 - UIView manipulation methods result in EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iOS 9.3 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

Common UIView manipulation methods are not working when testing on iOS 9.3 simulators in Xcode 9.0.1 as well as Xcode 9.1 beta 2.

So far, the methods that have caused crashes due to EXC_BAD_ACCESS at runtime are `insertSubview` and `layoutIfNeeded`.

Our app supports a minimum version of iOS 9 so it is important to us that we be able to properly test on this version in addition to the later versions.

Does anyone else run into this issue in their testing?

I'm not able to test in a previous version of Xcode because our .xib files have been formatted to make use of the Safe Area which Apple stated is backwards compatible. Regardless, these issues are all occurring due to programmatic view manipulation - not due to .xib file definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - I had recently duplicated the corresponding .xib file. The duplicated file switched it's "Builds for" option from our deployment target (iOS 9.0) to iOS 11.

Switching the "Builds for" option back to the deployment target seems to have fixed my issue.